# Dynamic localization with Data Annotations possible?

Tags: silverlight, dynamic, localization, data-annotations

I'm trying to dynamicly update the language of a Silverlight application. I tried the example provided by Tim Heuer and that was exactly wat I needed. 
[Silverlight and localizing string data](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/08/26/silverlight-string-localization.aspx)

Now I'm experimenting with Data Annotations and would like to have the same behaviour.But with no luck...
Can someone point me in the right direction.

DataAnnotation of a property:

```
[Display(Name = "UserNameLabel", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Strings.StringResources))]
[Required]
public string Username
...
```

My Xaml:

```
<dataInput:Label Target="{Binding ElementName=tbUserName}" PropertyPath="UserName"/> 
<TextBox x:Name="tbUserName" Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Thanks,
Ron